# App-switching confusion on a fresh OS X SnowLeopard 10.6 system

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro

I am a new Mac user with an early 2008 MacBook, and I have a fresh installation of SnowLeopard 10.6. When I use `CMD + TAB` I can switch between running applications. But when I switch / choose between another app with this command all that appears is the menu bar of the app, current window stays the same. e.g. I am in Firefox, switching to Finder the top menu bar changes to Finder but Firefox window stays in front. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I found [an article on cnet.com](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10329704-263.html?tag=mfiredir) that suggests restarting the Dock. To do this, launch `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`, select the Dock process, and press the Quit Process toolbar button.
2. If #1 doesn't help, the article states that you should try deleting this file: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.db` and restarting your computer.
3. A comment on discussion.info.apple.com indicates that removing login items sometimes corrects the problem. To check your login items, open System Preferences, go to Users, select your account, then select the Login Items tab.

Comment: Hey bneely Ive deleted the `com.apple.dock.db` and now it works like a charme! Great Tip thanks!